# Local Notification trigger everytime when opening application

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have to trigger a local notification at 5:30AM and that is working. But the problem is the notification is also getting triggered whenever I open my application. Here is my code in my `MainActivity`:

in my `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`:

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

Here is my `MyStartServiceReceiver`:

```
public class MyStartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.e("AlarmReceiver", "Started");
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        intent1.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + System.currentTimeMillis()));
        context.startService(intent1);
    }
}
```

Why is it triggering everytime I am opening my application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting alarm current date 5:05AM, if it is already passed alarm will be triggered immediately. To stop it do like this.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > calendar.getTimeInMillis()) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

What we are doing here is, if time already passed we are adding date by +1 so it will start from next date and we are cancelling previous set alarm.

Answer (score 2):

Because you create

```
Calendar.getInstance()
```

for example at 9AM, but set time 5:30AM in the past. So when you use

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

it has already happened.

You can use this

```
if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Comment: So what can be the possible solution. How can I avoid trigger notification everytime when I open my application ?

Comment: will this trigger the notification next day at 5:30AM ?

Comment: Or today if you use this condition 
`if(calendar.getTimeInMillis() < System.currentTimeMillis())`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 100, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    if(calendar.getTime().after(new Date())){
    calendar.set(Calendar.Date,1);
    }
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```